# Configuring grails spring security plugin work with documentdb

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, azure-cosmosdb, grails-spring-security

Kindly help me to connect grails spring security plugin to work with DocumentDB for storing and retrieving the credentials. I am not using gorm to work with DocumentDB in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/#_token_storage

The tokens are stored on the server using a tokenStorageService bean. The plugin comes with out-of-the-box support for JWT, Memcached, GORM and Grails Cache, but you can use your own strategy implementing the TokenStorageServiceinterface.

You need to implement TokenStorageService interface to connect to DocumentDB using the Azure DocumentDB Java SDK. 
Please let me know if you need help on this.